# Error when replacing new factor levels in test dataset with `NA`

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, predict, levels

I have split my data set into testing and training data sets. I've tried to fit a regression on the training set, and then use predict on the testing set.  When I do this I get an error message that says: "Error in model.frame factor x has New Levels". I know this is because there are levels in my testing data not seen in my training data.

What I want to do is just eliminate or ignore the levels that aren't in both data sets. I've tried to do this, but it isn't setting any levels to `NA`, and the `id` object says "integer (empty)":

```
id <- which(!(test$x %in% levels (train$x))
train$x[id] <- NA

fit <- lm(y ~ x, data=train)
P <- predict(fit,test)
```

Comment: But even before needing to add the droplevels command, the first part isn't working properly.  It seems that I either get an empty integer, or an error saying that the replacement has 190708 rows, data has 189590.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get "replacement length differs" error with your code.

```
id <- which(!(test$x %in% levels (train$x))
```

tells you what elements in `test$x` are not in `levels(train$x)`, so you should use `id` to index `test$x`, not `train$x`, when doing replacement.

```
test$x[id] <- NA
test$x <- droplevels(test$x)  ## also don't forget to remove unused factor levels

fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = train)
P <- predict(fit, test)
```

All data in `train` will be used to build your linear regression model. Some predictions in `P` will be `NA`.

---

> I'm still unable to get the `id` object to correctly identify which levels are not in both data sets. In the work-space it just shows `integer(0)`.

Then, what is the point of your question??!! All levels in `test$x` are inside `levels(train$x)` and there is no new level.

Comment: I'm still unable to get the Id object to correctly identify which levels are not in both data sets. In the work-space it just shows integer (empty).

Comment: Because I get an error message that says "Error in model.frame factor x has new levels." This seems to suggest that all the levels in test$x are not in train$x.